# Automata-Regular Expression

Tags: automata, computation-theory

I'm having problem understanding regular expression.

I was trying this exercise:

Over the alphabet {a,b}, create a regular expression that:

**A) Accept all the words that contains at least one occurrence 'a' or 'b'.**

epsilon*(a U b )

**B) Accept all the words that have at maximum three 'a´s'**

**C)All the words that ends with double letters (eg. abb ou abaa)**

epsilon*( aa U bb)

**D)The words has exact one occurrence three aaa( eg. abaaab or baaab)**

So, as you can see i'm having a lot of problems with regular expressions, i did the A and C ,but i think they're wrong, B e D i have no idea how to do.

Can i have some help..

Answer (score 1):

A) Σ*.(a + b) 
B) b* + b*.a.b* + b*.a.b*.a.b* + b*.a.b*.a.b*.a.b*
C) Σ*.(aa + bb)
D) (a.b + a.a.b + b*)*.aaa.(b.a + b.a.a + b*)*

You got A) and C) right idea-wise. Also, it's Sigma for alphabet, not epsilon. And you do not use **U** in regular expressions. It is expressed with the **+** symbol. Only operations allowed are: 
∅ - the empty set 
ε - the empty word 
a, b - terminals in the alphabet 
+ for unification 
* for 0+ symbols 
. for concatenation